# How to check all timestamps of a file?

Tags: linux, timestamp, date-modified

Is there a command in Linux to check all timestamps of a file?

I'm trying to see the last modified, created, and touched dates on the file.

Comment: Just to point out, Linux files don't have birth dates. Thus, it's not possible to determine the date a file was created.

Comment: noticed that =(. Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: @FatalError: Various filesystems already support birth/creation timestamps; the real trouble is in *accessing* such extra information. (One can't just extend `struct stat` without breaking things, unfortunately...) You can try out `debugfs -R "stat <1234>" /dev/sdXY` for ext4, replacing `1234` with an ino.

Comment: @grawity: Neat! I always wondered why no fs had it... but I guess they do, but like you said, can't just go breaking the ABI for existing binaries. Thanks for the tip :).

Comment: @FatalError: So why does `stat <file>` show a `Birth` timestamp that is the time when `<file>` was created? Is it just a coincidence? Is it the birthdate of the inode?

Comment: @FatalError, Birth time can be displayed with Linux `stat` command,  see [How to find creation date of file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91197/16640) and [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562/16640).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The command is called [`stat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28Unix%29).

```
$ stat test
234881026 41570368 -rw-r--r-- 1 werner staff 0 0 "Feb  7 16:03:06 2012" "Feb  7 16:03:06 2012" "Feb  7 16:03:06 2012" "Feb  7 16:03:06 2012" 4096 0 0 test
```

If you want to adjust the format, refer to the man pages, since the output is OS-specific and varies under Linux/Unix.

Generally, you can get the times through a normal directory listing as well:

- `ls -l` outputs last time the file content was modified, the `mtime`
- `ls -lc` outputs last time of file status modification, the `ctime` ([What's the difference?](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/20526-mtime-ctime-atime.html))
- `ls -lu` outputs last access time, the `atime` (although the usefulness of this concept is [subject to discussion](http://lwn.net/Articles/244829/))

And of course, `ctime` does not record when a file was "created".
The POSIX specification defines only three timestamps, but [some Linux filesystems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7562/16640) store Birth Time/Creation Time. [How to find creation date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91197/1664) On such a supported configuration, one could use

```
stat --printf '%n\nmtime: %y\nctime: %z\natime: %x\ncrtime:%w\n'
```

Comment: _`stat`_ is really detailed. But _`ls`_ only needs one line. It would be good if it could also display seconds. However, when creating lists of files, the former one is perfectly suitable.

Comment: ls -l was the quick solution for me

Comment: I've noticed that the result of `ls -l` can show a different date format when there is BusyBox installed (on Android). I think that without it , it's like "2019-07-26 14:41" , and with it, it's like "May  6 21:27" . How come the year is missing ? Is there a way to force it using the format of without it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Like I said, the answer depends on the OS. I think you should open a new question. If you are talking about Android specifically, perhaps [SO] or [Android.SE] would be more fitting.

Comment: @slhck Well it's the same OS, just with BusyBox installed. I asked if it's possible (meaning : is there a command to use) to get the format that will be shown.

Answer (score 25):

There are only **THREE** distinct time values stored for each of your files, as defined by the *POSIX Standard* : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ (see *Base Definitions* section -> 4. General Concepts -> 4.8 File Times Update)

> Each file has three distinct associated timestamps: the time of last **data access**, the time of last **data modification**, and the time the **file status last changed**. These values are returned in the file characteristics structure struct stat, as described in *[<sys/stat.h>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_stat.h.html)*.

And from *<sys/stat.h>* :

```
atime is for Last data access timestamp.
mtime is for Last data modification timestamp.
ctime is for Last file status change timestamp.
```

---

Following examples show the difference among the ***atime***, ***mtime*** and ***ctime***, these examples are in GNU/Linux BASH. You can use `stat -x` in Mac OS X or other BSD Dist. to see the similar output format.

```
$ stat --version
stat (GNU coreutils) 8.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Michael Meskes.
$
$ touch test
$ stat test
  File: `test'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 98828525    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  514/    rank)   Gid: (  514/    rank)
Access: 2014-03-16 10:58:28.609223953 +0800
Modify: 2014-03-16 10:58:28.609223953 +0800
Change: 2014-03-16 10:58:28.609223953 +0800
```

When the file is just created, the three timestamps are the same.

---

## 1. atime

First, let's **access** the file's data by reading it (`less` or `vim`), printing it out (`cat`) or copy it to another file (`cp`).

```
$ cat test #Nothing will be printed out, since the file is empty
$ stat test
  File: `test'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 98828525    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  514/    rank)   Gid: (  514/    rank)
Access: 2014-03-16 10:59:13.182301069 +0800  <-- atime Changed!
Modify: 2014-03-16 10:58:28.609223953 +0800
Change: 2014-03-16 10:58:28.609223953 +0800
```

---

## 2. ctime

Now let's **change** the file status, by changing the permission (`chmod`) or renaming it (`mv`)

```
$ chmod u+x test
$ stat test
  File: `test'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 98828525    Links: 1
Access: (0764/-rwxrw-r--)  Uid: (  514/    rank)   Gid: (  514/    rank)
Access: 2014-03-16 10:59:13.182301069 +0800
Modify: 2014-03-16 10:58:28.609223953 +0800
Change: 2014-03-16 11:04:10.178285430 +0800  <-- ctime Changed!
$    
$ mv test testing
$ stat testing
  File: `testing'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 98828525    Links: 1
Access: (0764/-rwxrw-r--)  Uid: (  514/    rank)   Gid: (  514/    rank)
Access: 2014-03-16 10:59:13.182301069 +0800
Modify: 2014-03-16 10:58:28.609223953 +0800
Change: 2014-03-16 11:06:33.342207679 +0800  <-- ctime Changed again!
```

Note that until now, the contents (**data**) of the file is still the same as when it was created.

---

## 3. mtime

Finally, let's **modify** the contents of the file by editing the file.

```
$ echo 'Modify the DATA of the file' > testing
$ echo 'Modify the DATA of the file also change the file status' > testing
$ stat testing
  File: `testing'
  Size: 56          Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 98828525    Links: 1
Access: (0764/-rwxrw-r--)  Uid: (  514/    rank)   Gid: (  514/    rank)
Access: 2014-03-16 10:59:13.182301069 +0800
Modify: 2014-03-16 11:09:48.247345148 +0800  <-- mtime Changed!
Change: 2014-03-16 11:09:48.247345148 +0800  <-- ctime also Changed!
```

---

## 4. birth time

Also note that the newer versions of `stat` (e.g. `stat --version 8.13` in Ubuntu 12.04) have a 4th timestamp - the **Birth Time** (file creation time). Although it may not show the correct time for now:

```
$ stat --version
stat (GNU coreutils) 8.13
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Michael Meskes.
$
$ stat birth_time
  File: `birth_time'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 4073946     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ bingyao)   Gid: ( 1000/ bingyao)
Access: 2014-03-16 10:46:48.838718970 +0800
Modify: 2014-03-16 10:46:48.838718970 +0800
Change: 2014-03-16 10:46:48.838718970 +0800
 Birth: -
```

Comment: What is the meaning of 10:46:48.838718970?  HH:MM:SS. nanoseconds?

Comment: [Yes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html). *"Since kernel 2.5.48, the stat structure supports nanosecond resolution for the three file timestamp fields...."*

Comment: Creation time can be figured out with root access and debugfs if needed: http://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/

Comment: Birth time… gladly. Because last modified and last change is nearly for the same purpose but still distinct. It is good if ***all** four* exist.